# C# Newtonsoft Json Writing in as [Json] instead of just JSON

Tags: c#

I am using C# to parse from ninjatrader given data every minute, which is then read in and inserted into a json file, currently it looks like the following:
[image]

Which is okay but I need it to be in the following format:

```
[
{Data1},
{Data2},
...
{DataN}
]
```

or just

```
{Data1},
{Data2},
...
{DataN}
```

without the `[]`

The following is my current code:

```
public class DataFormat
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double PriceChange { get; set; }
    public double RSI { get; set; }
    public double Momentum { get; set; }
    public double MACD { get; set; }
}


sw = File.AppendText(path);  // Open the path for writing

List<DataFormat> _data = new List<DataFormat>();
_data.Add(new DataFormat()
{
    Date = Time[0],
    PriceChange = Close[0] - Open[0],
    RSI = RSI(20, 3)[0],
    Momentum = Momentum(20)[0],
    MACD = MACD(12, 26, 9)[0]
});
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
sw.WriteLine(json);
sw.Close(); // Close the file to allow future calls to access the file again.
```

What is the best way to get it to read in as a JSON {}?

Comment: So you serialize one object at a time and then adding it to a file. So just remove List<DataFormat> and instead just do _data = new DataFormat()
Then the only thing you would need to do is to add ","  - you need to add it manually, basically sw.WriteLine($"{json},").

Comment: @NikitaChayka That worked, if you post that in answers i can mark it as correct.

Comment: JSON is not meant to be read or written line by line - it is serialized object data

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I could agree with you. Except there are actually cases when you still WRITE it line by line - example could be "structured" logging to a file

Comment: And thanks @LaneFloyd )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logic you serialize one object at a time and then adding it to a file. So just remove `List<DataFormat>` and instead just do `_data = new DataFormat()` Then the only thing you would need to do is to add "," - you need to add it manually, basically `sw.WriteLine($"{json},")`